# Why does "key:value" order change while inserting a row in a table with JSON data type field in MySQL 5.7.34?

Tags: mysql

I am inserting data into a table with one column of `JSON` data type in `phpMyAdmin` running on `MySQL 5.7.34`. But the order of **key:value** in JSON string is changed after successful insertion.

For example

This is my `tb_products` table:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_products (
    product_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    product_name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    product_attributes json NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);
```

[image]

I inserted a new row using following `SQL`:

```
INSERT INTO tb_products (product_name, product_attributes) 
VALUES ('Samsung Galaxy J7 Pro', '{"color":"black", "ram":"3 GB", "storage":"64 GB", "battery": "3600 mAh"}');
```

The row is inserted successfully in the `tb_products` table but when I browsed data in this table, `phpMyAdmin` shows the `key:value` order is changed:

[image]

[image]

You can clearly see that the order of `key:value` is not the same what I had while inserting in the table through my query.

- Why the `key:value` order is changed?
- What logic MySQL applies while doing this sorting or shuffling?
- Is there any way to keep my original `key:value` order?

Comment: The JSON standard does not require key:value pairs to have any ordering, so there is nothing wrong with what MySQL is doing here.  Why do you need to care about this perceived order?  (Note that the order of elements inside JSON _arrays_ definitely does matter, and MySQL will maintain this order).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I encountered this weird behaviour a few days ago so I thought I should have asked about this abnormality on STO so that I can get some valid reason or logic behind this. I have also found that people haven't talked about this issue on Internet- that's strange!

Comment: Did you read my comment above?  `{"a": 1, "b": 2}` and `{"b": 2, "a": 1}` are both logically equal JSON.  From your point of view, there is no "order" to the keys.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes of course. I did read your comment. I know order of `key:value` pairs in `JSON` does NOT matter but does matter in `indexed array` (in `JSON array` as well). My only question was, what difference would it make to MySQL if it had saved the data as I provided it?

Comment: You don't have an array there.

Answer (score -1):

Try this method, all you need to do is review the array processing method in php.

[
{
"name": "Name1",
"val": "val2"
},
{
"name": "Name2",
"val": "val2"
}
]

Comment: What is "this method"? If you want to process anything in PHP, why not share the code involved?